# Unable to understand the output shapes in LSTM network below

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, nlp

I have been trying to train a bidirectional LSTM using TensorFlow v2 keras for text classification. Below is the architecture:

```
  model1 = Sequential()
  model1.add(Embedding(vocab, 128,input_length=maxlength))

  model1.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32,dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True)))
  model1.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16,dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True)))
  model1.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
  model1.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
  model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

  model1.summary()
```

Now, it is the summary details where I am confused

[image]

My doubts are related to the output shapes of BiLSTM layers. How they are (283,64) & (283,32) though the number of units used is 32 & 16 respectively for the 2 layers. Here, maxlength=283, vocab=19479

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the explanation for this result is the bidirectional Nature of the LSTM layers in which you have added to your neural network: The size of the layer you have added is doubled for the layer to also learn the sequence backwards. I hope you can understand, if you have any questions, you can ask me in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `Bidirectional`. If you remove it, you'll see that output shapes are *(283,32) & (283,16)*. `Bidirectional` creates some kind of extra layer